# Null check on a date field inside a template

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm trying to prevent a 'null' being displayed on the UI with this template:

```
template: '# if (PassExpiryDate !== null) {# #=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(PassExpiryDate), "dd-MMM-yy")# #} else {# &nbsp #}#'
```

Where the date is available, it shows a formatted date but it still shows a null as well.

[image]

Can someone pinpoint the issue with the client template?

**Update**

Tried another one but with no luck:

```
template: '#= typeof PassExpiryDate == "undefined" || PassExpiryDate == null ? "" : kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(PassExpiryDate), "dd-MMM-yy") #'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is do

```
... else { # <span></span> # } #
```

Comment: did you try (PassExpiryDate !== "null") ? it looks as though the value is actually null, so if its being passed in as a string, then you need to set the value to a string, then it should work as the string being passed is "null"